# C How to validate input in a loop Without using break

Tags: c, validation, loops

Ho do I validate an input each time in a loop with out having an infinite loop that shows error in validation with out using break:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int count;


for(count=1; count<6;count++) {
    int input;
    printf("Please enter a number 1-5:");

    if(!scanf("%d",&input)){
        printf("nil");
        scanf("%d",&input);

    }

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Have you ever heard of a do-while loop? If not, look it up. Otherwise, use it. You can circumvent the `break` with a `goto` or a flag anyway, so "with out [sic] using break" is pointless here.

Comment: If you don't want to use a `break` then don't call `break`? It's not clear what you are asking. Don't tell us what you *don't* want to do. Tell us what do you want to do if the validation fails.

Comment: I cant use break or goto, i need to go through 5 inputs to process but they must be integer

Comment: Then use a do-while loop. Makes for cleaner code and is easy to write.

Comment: Use a `while` or `do/while` loop which  has an exit condition on a counter that only increments on successful validation.

Comment: It still gives me the infinite error resutl

Comment: Well show that code! Do you expect us to tell you what you did wrong without seeing the code?

Comment: What is your objection to using `break`? You have multiple conditions to satisfy (valid input, number range, number of attempts), as well as preventing an input block when the input is refused by `%d` format.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps like this. It checks for valid input, but because there is difficulty dumping input to `scanf` when it is not accepted (such as a string for a number), I read the line with `fgets`, and if it is faulty, forget it and get another input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int input, attempts = 0;
    char str[100];
    do {
        if(++attempts == 6) {
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Please enter a number 1-5: ");
        if(fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
    } while(sscanf(str, "%d", &input) != 1 || input < 1 || input > 5);
    printf("You entered %d\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

Program session

```
Please enter a number 1-5: -1
Please enter a number 1-5: 42
Please enter a number 1-5: obi
Please enter a number 1-5: 3
You entered 3
```